# "Store upgrade failed" when upgrading Octez node from v15.1 to v16

Tags: node, upgrade, octez

After updating our Docker image to v16 from v15.1, we see the following error in the logs after Octez shuts down:

```
Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Updating the node configuration...
Mar 21 18:16:32.983 - node.main: FULL access to RPC enabled; this is very risky.
Mar 21 18:16:32.983 - node.main:   (addresses = [::]:8732, 0.0.0.0:8737)
Mar 21 18:16:33.006 - node.config.validation: the node configuration has been successfully validated.
Mar 21 18:16:43.540 - node.data_version: upgrading data directory from 2.0 to 3.0
Mar 21 18:16:43.540 - node.store: upgrading the store
Mar 21 18:16:50.367 - node.store: store upgrade failed, cleaning up temporary files: Error:
Mar 21 18:16:50.367 - node.store:                                                      Not_found
Mar 21 18:16:50.367 - node.store: 
Mar 21 18:16:50.372 - node.data_version: failed to upgrade storage: Error:
Mar 21 18:16:50.372 - node.data_version:                              Not_found
Mar 21 18:16:50.372 - node.data_version: 
octez-node: Error:
              Not_found
```

Invoking the upgrade command directly using `docker run -v mainnet-rolling_tezos-data:/var/run/tezos/node tezos/tezos:v16.0 octez-upgrade-storage` runs into the same issue:

```
Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Mar 21 18:24:33.028 - node.data_version: upgrading data directory from 2.0 to 3.0
Mar 21 18:24:33.028 - node.store: upgrading the store
Mar 21 18:24:40.177 - node.store: store upgrade failed, cleaning up temporary files: Error:
Mar 21 18:24:40.177 - node.store:                                                      Not_found
Mar 21 18:24:40.177 - node.store: 
Mar 21 18:24:40.183 - node.data_version: failed to upgrade storage: Error:
Mar 21 18:24:40.183 - node.data_version:                              Not_found
Mar 21 18:24:40.183 - node.data_version: 
octez-node: Error:
              Not_found
```

This is a rolling node that is about a year old. It was synced from scratch.

UPDATE: Updating the Docker image to v16.1 did not fix the issues:

```
Current public chain: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Local chain data: 2018-06-30T16:07:32Z.
Updating the node configuration...
Mar 23 22:44:55.749 - node.main: FULL access to RPC enabled; this is very risky.
Mar 23 22:44:55.749 - node.main:   (addresses = [::]:8732, 0.0.0.0:8737)
Mar 23 22:44:55.797 - node.config.validation: the node configuration has been successfully validated.
Mar 23 22:45:06.290 - node.data_version: upgrading data directory from 2.0 to 3.0
Mar 23 22:45:06.290 - node.store: upgrading the store
Mar 23 22:45:13.716 - node.store: store upgrade failed, cleaning up temporary files:
Mar 23 22:45:13.716 - node.store:   Error:
Mar 23 22:45:13.716 - node.store:     Failed to upgrade block BMUMeUBzxMn3NJ272Ji8PWv2gD4rVTcUzqomMZxhpPs3FVhrHWd (level 3222226) for RO_TMP floating store: block not found in the index.
Mar 23 22:45:13.716 - node.store: 
Mar 23 22:45:13.722 - node.data_version: failed to upgrade storage:
Mar 23 22:45:13.722 - node.data_version:   Error:
Mar 23 22:45:13.722 - node.data_version:     Failed to upgrade block BMUMeUBzxMn3NJ272Ji8PWv2gD4rVTcUzqomMZxhpPs3FVhrHWd (level 3222226) for RO_TMP floating store: block not found in the index.
Mar 23 22:45:13.722 - node.data_version: 
octez-node: Error:
              Failed to upgrade block BMUMeUBzxMn3NJ272Ji8PWv2gD4rVTcUzqomMZxhpPs3FVhrHWd (level 3222226) for RO_TMP floating store: block not found in the index.
```

Any ideas on how we can get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the node is in an unexpected state where a block is stored but not indexed. We could discard the upgrade of that block but it seems a better idea to start with a new storage thanks to a snapshot import. As you are using a rolling note, this will be very quick.
Additionally, as your rolling node is running since a year, importing a snapshot will enable the garbage collection of the storage and will drastically reduce the disk usage of your node.